# Can we create Air Mobile apps with Haxe in flashdevelop?

Tags: air, flashdevelop, haxe

i was wondering if **Mobile** air apps can be created with haxe 2.10 in flashdevelop 4.0.4 RTM?

note: not using NME

thanks

Comment: Why the downvote? Please at least leave a brief comment what you think is wrong with the question...

Comment: Sure, it could. I don't have enough time now to explain full routine. But just try to 'haxelib install air3', write some code in Haxe and compile it using Flex/AIR tools. Then package generated "swf" like ordinar AS3 AIR app.

If you need more info, I could write detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've created AIR Mobile apps from Haxe, but only indirectly.

I compiled to a .SWF and used Adobe's free AIR compiler to convert the SWF to an AIR app. I successfully deployed this without too much headache to iOS, Android, and Blackberry.